# The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))

Tags: c#, .net-framework-version, comexception, visio2013, visio-2010

I have an application which opens an Visio file .VSD and copies some jpeg images onto the VSD file. I am using Visio 2013, it works fine with this version but I have another client machine where I have only exe of this application(not complete code base) and has Visio 2010 in that client machine. when I run the application and select the Visio .vsd file, it throw the above subjected error.

Struggling to understand whether problem with exe, code, version or dlls?
May I know what could be the fix or some workaround?
My code to open the visio application that's where the exception is thrown is below,

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application();
 application.Visible = true;

                                     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Document doc = null;
                 OpenFileDialog filedg = new OpenFileDialog();
                 filedg.Title = "Select VSD template file";
                 filedg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
                 filedg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                 filedg.FilterIndex = 2;
                 filedg.RestoreDirectory = true;
                 if (filedg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                 {
                     LogMessageToFile("Opening Visio template");
                     if(application == null)
                     {
                         LogMessageToFile("Visio application is NULL");
                         return;
                     }
                     LogMessageToFile("Filename" + filedg.FileName);
                     doc = application.Documents.Open(filedg.FileName);
```

Comment: Which code line throws this exception?

Comment: doc = application.Documents.Open(filedg.FileName); this where exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

*"it works fine with this version but I have another client machine where I have only exe of this application"* -

From my experience, if this happens only on several computers, the problem is that the EXE you are running has **insufficiant priviligaes** to use InterOp or Visio itself.

Try running the EXE with "Run as administrator".