# Call Excel VBA file from C# 0x80010105 error

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I been trying to call a VBA function from c# to automate some process, the problem is that when the Excel.Application visibility is false I get this error:

> The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))

When the visibility is true everything works perfectly but the it opens the excel application and I need to keep this process in the background not in the foreground, any idea?

Thanks!

[Just works when visible is true, if not I get:  "The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT)" )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYyC5.png)

```
Function DetermineStructureUpdates(DataDBPathAndName As String, DataCopyDBPathAndName As String, SyncDBPathAndName As String, DataDBPw As String, SyncDBPw As String) As String
dbDataPathAndName = DataDBPathAndName
dbDataCopyPathAndName = DataCopyDBPathAndName
dbSyncPathAndName = SyncDBPathAndName
dbDataPW = DataDBPw
dbSyncPW = SyncDBPw
AppActivate Application.Caption 'Bring Excel to the foreground
On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
Call DetermineDBStructure
If ErrorMessage <> "" Then GoTo ErrorHandling
DetermineStructureUpdates = "Success"
Exit Function
```

ErrorHandling:
    DetermineStructureUpdates = ErrorToReturn
End Function

Comment: convert the vba code / function to C# can you show the VBA code?

Comment: check this [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43648735/the-server-threw-an-exception-exception-from-hresult-0x80010105-rpc-e-server)

Comment: Is your VBA code using `.Select` anywhere?

Comment: @MethodMan I wish but I can't because there's some functions that are working in a old system and must be used.

Comment: @user12345 Yes, part of the implementation has some selects

Comment: what does the old system have to do with the new.. I have done this many of times and if the old system is not aware of the new code then you should have zero issues..

Comment: @ByronJosueSerranoNuñez well, there you go. Your VBA function fails due to calling `.Select` on a hidden workbook. Revise the parts that use `.Select` and you should be fine.